# SQL Server language

Tags: sql, sql-server

In northwind database Find the manager who has the maximum number of people reporting to him/her. I have written a query:

```
Select reportsto from 
    (select top 1 reportsto,
    count(reportsto)from employees group by 
    reportsto order by count(reportsto) desc)
```

but it gives an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: try to do some basic debug before ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

This not oh-so-very-clear message means that you need to put an alias after the said (the last) bracket. It is a requirement with SQL Server that you must assign an alias to a subselect. So, it should be like this:

```
Select reportsto from 
    (select top 1 reportsto,
    count(reportsto)from employees group by 
    reportsto order by count(reportsto) desc) s  /* 's' is just an example,
                                                    you can assign any alias */
```

Note that this doesn't apply to subqueries used with predicates like `IN`, `EXISTS`, `ANY/SOME`, `ALL`. In this case, you are directly pulling data from a subselect, and that is precisely the case when the subselect must be aliased.

On a different note, what you are attempting to do in your query does not really require a subselect. This would do just as well:

```
select top 1 reportsto
from employees
group by reportsto
order by count(reportsto) desc
```

That is, you can simply remove the `COUNT()` column from the SELECT clause and use the rest of the subquery as is, the result would be the same as with your original intent. Unless there's more to it than what we can see, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a space after `count(reportsto)`.

---

```
count(reportsto) from
```

instead of

```
count(reportsto)from
```

Comment: I have altered space But i want who is the manager in northwind database using query in the employee table

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employees
WHERE  EmployeeID IN (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ReportsTo
                      FROM   Employees
                      GROUP  BY ReportsTo
                      ORDER  BY COUNT(ReportsTo) DESC)
```

The `WITH TIES` option means that if more than one manager has the maximum number of people reporting to them you will get details for all of them.